# monotouch bindings project to framework

Tags: xamarin.ios

What are the correct steps to creating a bindings project for a Framework versus a library? (Yes, they are close to the same thing, but NOT the same, the framework is a directory structure with header files, library and resources). These are what I've come up with, note that none of the Framework specific steps are documented as far as I can tell at the Xamarin web site (please prove me wrong).

1. Create the bindings project via MonoDevelop wizard.
2. Generate the ApiDefinition.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs files with btouch or by hand.
3. Copy the  file from the root of the framework directory to lib.a (e.g., ArcGIS to libArcGIS.a) and add it to the project. It is important to note that the file without any file extension in the framework directory is in fact a library file.
4. ?? Include framework resources ??

You'll notice that I get foggy at the third step. How to you add these resources to the bindings project? The large part of the bindings project links and runs fine, but I think it crashes at times because it is missing an expected resource.

Answer (score 0):

You must (a) create a C# contract that describes the Objective-C contracts and how you want your projection into C# to look like, and (b) statically distribute the library with your project.

To kick the automatic population of the linkwith.cs you must rename the framework library (for example MyFramework) to use the library pattern (in this case, "libMyFramework.a")

Resources you have to select and flag as resources, they will be bundled directly into your app, and extracted when the library is consumed.

Comment: I already had the first three steps complete (all 11K lines and 30+ class) What I don't get is to what to do with the resources, how are they included in the project? Which project?